# When doing the accessibility analysis, the value of Mean was very low

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, sdna

When I did the accessibility analysis, the value of BtA500c was very low, mostly lower than 0.05. The final mean value was also very low. Two of the short lines are high. I don't know why.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted the author behind sdna?

Comment: That would be me - I prefer people to ask questions here so the answers are searchable by others

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming your analysis is not using origin/destination weights)

Possibly your projection is not what you think. Check the length of lines as output by sDNA (`LLen` / `Link Length`, not to be confused with length in radius `Length R500`). I suspect whatever units you are using that most lines are much longer than 500 of them, so only a small fraction of each link falls inside the radius and betweenness is low except in cases where the links are short.

At the same time it's worth checking Link Connectivity `LConn` looks like you would expect (*the number of other link ends each link is connected to*) to make sure the links are connected where you think.